# Como fazer um usuário no SQL Server 2008 visualizar apenas uma VIEW?

Tags: sql, sql-server, login, view, sql-server-2008

Fiz uma `View` para enviar a um cliente, mas não posso passar o login e senha de acesso geral para o mesmo. Dessa forma criei um usuário (`cliente_view`) e gostaria que esse visualizasse apenas a View criada (View_consulta_vendas).

- Como fazer esse processo acima?

Comment: Gabriel, eu encontrei essa Pergunta no [DataBase Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17177/how-to-add-a-user-with-access-to-a-single-view). Ai diz que você deve conceder acesso a esse usuário. Talvez a pergunta pode lhe se útil, se conseguir posta o resultado pra gente na resposta :)

Comment: No seu usuário, execute o comando que dá permissão: `GRANT SELECT ON dbo.MyViewName TO username;`

Comment: Você pode criar o usuário, não atribuir a nenhum grupo, e dar acesso somente na `view` usando o comando: `GRANT SELECT ON View_consulta_vendas TO cliente_view`

Comment: Marconi, Everson e Ricardo.

Primeiramente obrigado pela atenção.

Realizei o processo descrito pelos senhores e consegui criar o login ao banco de dados, criar o usuário e vincular ao login e permitir que esse visualize apenas a view, com os script's abaixo:

CREATE LOGIN cliente_view WITH PASSWORD = 'cliente123'

USE SISTEMA_CLIENTE

CREATE USER cliente_view for login cliente_view

GRANT SELECT ON view_consulta_vendas_cliente TO cliente_view

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa dar a esse usuário que criou (`cliente_view`) o privilégio que deseja, no seu caso, para dar acesso somente para permissão de `SELECT`, utilize o [`GRANT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql):

```
GRANT SELECT ON view_consulta_vendas TO cliente_view;
```

---

Obs: como já criou o usuário, verifique quais permissões ele já possui, caso deseje remover alguma, utilize o [`REVOKE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revoke-transact-sql).

Comment: Muito obrigado Henrique, vou postar o que fiz abaixo para ajudar outros usuários!!

Answer (score 1):

Conforme ajuda do pessoal acima, consegui criar o Login para o Banco de Dados, criar o usuário e associar ao login acima e permitir que esse usuário visualize apenas aquela determinada view com os seguintes comandos:

```
-- Criando Login para o SQL:
CREATE LOGIN cliente_view WITH PASSWORD = 'cliente123'
-- Comando para selecionar o sistema:
USE SISTEMA_CLIENTE
-- Criando o usuário e associando ao login criado no processo acima:
CREATE USER cliente_view for login cliente_view
-- Liberando permissão para visualização da View pro usuário criado:
GRANT SELECT ON view_consulta_vendas_cliente TO cliente_view
```

Comment: Boa Gabriel! Bom que pude ajudar