# Criar usuário com acesso somente às views do Banco de Dados em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Como criar um usuário que visualize somente as `views` do meu banco de dados em MySQL?

Estou usando as seguintes configurações:

> Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS
>   MySQL: 5.5.55
>   Apache: 2.4.7
>   phpMyAdmin: 4.0.10

Comment: Relacionada: [Como fazer um usuário no SQL Server 2008 visualizar apenas uma VIEW?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215562/como-fazer-um-usu%C3%A1rio-no-sql-server-2008-visualizar-apenas-uma-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Acredito que se você utilizar a seguinte estrutura, você concederá as permissões apenas a view desejada

```
GRANT priv [(colunas)] [, priv [(colunas)]] ...
ON {*.* | db.* | db.sua_view}
TO usuario [IDENTIFIED BY 'senha']
[, usuario [IDENTIFIED BY 'senha']] ...
[WITH [GRANT OPTION |
```

Dê uma conferida neste link: [Gerenciamento de Usuários e Controle de Acessos do MySQL](http://www.devmedia.com.br/gerenciamento-de-usuarios-e-controle-de-acessos-do-mysql/1898)

Comment: Marcus, valeu!!!
Deu certinho!

Comment: Por nada ;). Por favor marque esta como a resposta correta.

Comment: Como marcar essa resposta como correta? Não vejo opção.

Comment: Tem um botão em formato de visto (" V ") abaixo das setas de positivar e negativar